# Fetching custom Authorization header from incoming PHP request

Tags: php, http-headers, authorization

So I'm trying to parse an incoming request in PHP which has the following header set:

```
Authorization: Custom Username
```

Simple question: how on earth do I get my hands on it?  If it was `Authorization: Basic`, I could get the username from `$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]`.  If it was `X-Custom-Authorization: Username`, I could get the username from `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_CUSTOM_AUTHORIZATION"]`.  But neither of these are set by a custom Authorization, `var_dump($_SERVER)` reveals no mention of the header (in particular, `AUTH_TYPE` is missing), and PHP5 functions like `get_headers()` only work on responses to outgoing requests.  I'm running PHP 5 on Apache with an out-of-the box Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you're only going to use Apache you might want to have a look at [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/apache_request_headers).

Comment: @halfdan: else ? i am using nginx and i am unable get authorization in header.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers/17490827#17490827

This page gives complete details about different server types and how to use the authorization, please do read the comments on the page as well

Comment: Check the php variable $_SERVER array in case your sites been redirected -> REDIRECT_AUTHORIZATION

Answer (score 70):

For token based auth:

```
  $token = null;
  $headers = apache_request_headers();
  if(isset($headers['Authorization'])){
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/Token token="(.*)"/', $headers['Authorization'], $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1])){
      $token = $matches[1];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 44):

Add this code into your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Pass your header like `Authorization: {auth_code}` and finally you get the Authorization code by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`

Note: The above one is for apache, if you're using the nginx you don't need to update anything. you can get the value easily in nginx like:

if you are passing `authorization` key, you can get the key value by just putting the `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`. just add `HTTP_` as the prefix in `$_SERVER` for get anything like

```
postman_token => HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN
test_key => HTTP_TEST_KEY
```

Answer (score 23):

Just use:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$token = $headers['token'];
```

Answer (score 12):

For background, why Apache filters away the `Authorization` header: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17490827

Solutions depending on which Apache module is used to pass the request to the application:

mod_wsgi, mod_fcgid:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30310338

cgi:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175451

Other hacks - massaging the headers in this question:

- [Request headers bag is missing Authorization header in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990388/request-headers-bag-is-missing-authorization-header-in-symfony-2)
- [Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM and Authorization headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers)

Answer (score 2):

```
otra solución php, esta esta disponible para todos los servidores a cambio apache_request_headers() solo aplica para apache...... 
$headers = getallheaders();
$token = null;

if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    $authorizationHeader = $headers['Authorization'];
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/Bearer (.+)/', $authorizationHeader, $matches)) {
        if (isset($matches[1])) {
            $token = $matches[1];
        }
    }
}

if ($token) {
    // El token está presente en la cabecera de autorización
    echo json_encode("Token recibido: " . $token);
} else {
    // El token no está presente en la cabecera de autorización
    echo json_encode("Error: Token no presente en la cabecera de autorización");
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is the English only version of stackoverflow. There are multiple other versions like .es, .pt etc.