# Request headers bag is missing Authorization header in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, http, symfony, http-headers, fiddler

I'm trying to implement a [custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) in Symfony 2. I'm sending a test request using Fiddler and printing all headers server side; well, `Authorization` header is missing.

Am i doing something wrong?

```
GET /RESTfulBackend/web/index.php HTTP/1.1
Authorization: FID 44CF9590006BF252F707:jZNOcbfWmD/
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
```

Listener just prints the headers and quits:

```php
class HMACListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    private $securityContext;

    private $authenticationManager;

    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        print_r($request->headers->all()); 
        die();
     }
}
```

Response is missing `Authorization` header:

```
Array
(
    [host] => Array
        (
            [0] => localhost
        )
    [user-agent] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fiddler
        )
    [accept] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml
        )
    [accept-language] => Array
        (
            [0] => it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
        )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorization header missing in django rest\_framework, is apache to blame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387516/authorization-header-missing-in-django-rest-framework-is-apache-to-blame)

Comment: Check also the answers [here in this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13387516/1697459)

Answer (score 65):

You must add this code to a **virtualhost** tag

It will not work if you put it in a **Directory** tag.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: this worked like a charm for me, can you just explain what it does?

Comment: Thank you that works, however there might be a problem. It looks like an authorization header field gets created even if it's not present in the incoming request. This should not be the behavior

Comment: that is right, it is creating an authorization header field even when none in the request, any ideas on the matter?

Comment: I added the following to the .htaccess: RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13387616/1697459).

Comment: this answer is working fine with http request, but it is not working with https requests

Comment: In my case it only works if the URL does not contain the bootstrap-script e.g. http://server.tld/some/path. It does not work for the following URL http://server.tld/app_dev.php/some/path

Comment: Worked when I added it to `.htaccess`

Comment: Worked in .htaccess too

Comment: where is the virtualhost tag? in my .htaccess i dont see it

Answer (score 34):

Akambi's answer didn't work for me, but found this answer in the php website:

"Workaround for missing Authorization header under CGI/FastCGI Apache:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

Now PHP should automatically declare $_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_*] variables if the client sends the Authorization header."

Thanks derkontrollfreak+9hy5l!

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the header is not sent?

Comment: Applied this fix but it's still not responding to 401 header in my script.

Comment: This is the only solution works, `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`'s one is not working

Comment: This worked for me by adding it in the VirtualHost config file. It should work fine in .htaccess too, just make sure there is no proxies, container etc in between before the request reaches your app.

Answer (score 20):

The verified solution worked for me at the time to get the Authorization header through. However, it generated an empty Authorization header when there was none in the incoming request. This is how I solved it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem when writing a public API with custom `Authorization` header. To fix the `HeaderBag` I used a listener:

```
namespace My\Project\Frontend\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

/**
 * Listener for the REQUEST event. Patches the HeaderBag because the
 * "Authorization" header is not included in $_SERVER
 */
class AuthenticationHeaderListener
{
    /**
     * Handles REQUEST event
     *
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event the event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->fixAuthHeader($event->getRequest()->headers);
    }
    /**
     * PHP does not include HTTP_AUTHORIZATION in the $_SERVER array, so this header is missing.
     * We retrieve it from apache_request_headers()
     *
     * @param HeaderBag $headers
     */
    protected function fixAuthHeader(HeaderBag $headers)
    {
        if (!$headers->has('Authorization') && function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
            $all = apache_request_headers();
            if (isset($all['Authorization'])) {
                $headers->set('Authorization', $all['Authorization']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and bound it to `kernel.request` in the service definition:

```
services:
  fix_authentication_header_listener:
    class: My\Project\Frontend\EventListener\AuthenticationHeaderListener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 255 }
```

Comment: Note that you need to intall PHP's Apache extension, in order to have the apache_request_headers function available.

Comment: Using symfony 5.4, - GetResponseEvent was renamed to RequestEvent.

Answer (score 7):

Authorization header is used for [http basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Example) which is discarded by apache if not in valid format. Try using another name.

Comment: Thanks. How for example Amazon S3 can use it? http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: Well if you see Apache implementation it expects the request token to be base_64 encoded string and on server side it base64_decodes the string and set `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` server variable. As you see the implementation is server specific. So Amazon S3 web servers have implemented the scheme differently.

Comment: What you would suggest then? using apache_request_headers() (apache specific) or using a custom header?

Comment: You can make an apache module to make your authentication scheme compliance with http basic authentication. For example check [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) module. Or you can use custom header e.g `X-FID-Authorization`.

Comment: AFAIK Apache will accept any format Authorization header. It is PHP which discards anything else than valid Basic or Digest header.

Comment: It seems that we can use the header name ''Php-Auth-Digest" as an alternative to "Authorization". see Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag::getHeaders()

Answer (score 7):

Another option that worked for Apache 2.4 when other options did not was to set the [`CGIPassAuth`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/de/mod/core.html#cgipassauth) option in the relevant `<Directory>` context, like this:

```
CGIPassAuth On
```

According to the documentation, it is available since Apache 2.4.13.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Otherwise the Authorization header was simply missing from both getallheaders and $_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change your `PHP` handler to run PHP as `Apache Module` instead of as `CGI application`.

Comment: Not a good solution though because it will be slower as module than as CGI. Also there are problems with the rights in cache and logs folder during the development.

Comment: @Jorj "problems" can you be more specific? I bet it is just a matter of configuration. It is a working solution. Never said it was the "best". That is a matter of opinion..

Comment: Sure, here is what happens: as a developer on a unix box you would create files under your user, right ? Then you would launch some commands from your console which would create files in cache and logs folder. If PHP is configured as module in Apache it will run with Apache's user, that is "www" or "nobody" or something similar. As a result it will try to overwrite the files created by you in cache and logs folders and it will throw errors because they belongs to another owner. Of course, there are workarounds to this too, but still is an additional headache.

Answer (score 0):

We should authorise this header "Authorization" on the server side,

it's also simply done with nelmioCorsBundle

`nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['Authorization']`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache and you already have a header override set in your .htaccess file but you're still getting 401 errors

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]
```

Then make sure you enable config overrides in your `VirtualHost`. Set the value to `All` for the `AllowOverride` parameter in the `Directory` tag

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory /var/www/***>
        AllowOverride All
        ...
    </Directory> 

</VirtualHost>
```

---

Don't forget to restart apache after making changes