# HTTP request header recognized by local server but not online server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rest, hosting

I made a simple PHP app that provides RESTful API for registering, logging in and updating user's geolocation. I tested it out with MySQL database on a local Apache sever and everything was fine.

Recently I migrated the PHP code to an online host *HostGator*. Part of my code stopped working when it involves recognizing HTTP request header. Like this:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Authorization: f0cc696e44f76f9638331b5487f4b01d
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4
```

I wrote my PHP code such that it reads the api-key under header *Authorization*. It worked fine on my local server but reported *api-key missing* when the same code was migrated on *HostGator*

I suspect there may be certain settings that are default in my local environment but need to be set explicitly in *HostGator*. Here's my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

I'm using *XAMPP* for local sever and database, and Chrome extension *Advanced Rest Client* for sending HTTP requests.

Edit: My code to retrieve the header value:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
    // validating api key
    // ...
} else {
    // api key is missing in header
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the authorization header for a custom API key.  That is not it's intention and Apache will discard Authorization headers that are invalid.
I learned that from [Request headers bag is missing Authorization header in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990388/request-headers-bag-is-missing-authorization-header-in-symfony-2)

So what you need to do is use an actual custom header.
Instead of using the Authorization field send your key as

```
X-Apikey: this_is_my_magic_key_that_put_in_the_header
```

then retrieve it as

```
$headers['X-Apikey'];
```

Apache won't discard that.

Note: the headers will get CamelCased on new words.  Sending "X-API-KEY" becomes "X-Api-Key" So use the format above to be able to retrieve it properly.

Comment: Nice insight about custom headers! Just in case, I solved it adding a rule to my _.htaccess_ file instead: `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the code for how you are retrieving the "Authorization" header

I'd recommend looking at the SERVER variables in your receiving PHP script.

```
$myauthorization=$_SERVER['HTTP_Authorization'];
```

It that doesn't work.  Check out the what's available

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! After putting in print_r, I get "Unexpected token A"... Not sure what that means

Comment: I figured out I had the "Unexpected token A" error because my server response was in json. So now it looks like the server receives regular headers such as "Accept-Language" just fine but not my custom headers

Comment: Post  your print_r($headers);

Comment: I did... See my first comment.
So if I take json response into account, $headers[Authorization] gives "null" but $headers[Accept-Language] gives "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4" which is correct

Answer (score 0):

**Authorization** is part of ***RFC 2617 - HTTP Authentication*** and it can't be used. Just rename it for another named and it will works fine.