# How do I retrieve basic auth credentials from Symfony's HttpFoundation component?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-foundation

I want to retrieve the basic authentication credentials from Symfony's HttpFoundation component. A cursory look at the docs reveals nothing; is there a way I can do it?

(I'm using the HttpFoundation component in an application not based on the Symfony framework.)

Comment: Normally they would be in the request header bag.  There used to be a problem as documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990388/request-headers-bag-is-missing-authorization-header-in-symfony-2  But I thought it was fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by basic auth credentials? In a controller you can just do $this->getUser()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The values of `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` can be accessed through an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` in the following manner:

```
$username = $request->headers->get('php-auth-user');
$password = $request->headers->get('php-auth-pw');
```

Comment: I can confirm this solution works in symfony 5.1 version also.