# Symfony lexikjwtauthbundle authenticate($token) EROOR

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I work on a `Rest API` with `symphony` and everything worked for me great in local, but after I deployed my project I can't login anymore and **"Bad credentials"** error keep showing up.

After comparing the behavior of the local and the deployed app I noticed that the problem is in `AuthentificationProviderManager` which can't solve: `$result = $provider->authenticate($token);` and catch an AuthenticationException.

So if anyone has an idea about how to fix this error or just know what the real problem is, please let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the deployed app sitting behind Apache or nginx? Does the authentication process require sending non-default headers in the HTTP request? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990388/request-headers-bag-is-missing-authorization-header-in-symfony-2

Comment: **Issue solved** : the issue was caused by the name of the table. Actually I didn't specify the table name `* @ORM\Table(name="user")`   and it worked for me locally but not after deployement. And thank you so much for your answer.