# Authorization header missing in django rest_framework, is apache to blame?

Tags: apache, apache2, authorization, mod-proxy, django-rest-framework

I've managed to extend `TokenAuthentication` and I have a working model when using the request session to store my tokens, however when I attempt to pass `Authorization` as a header parameter [as described here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#custom-authentication), I noticed that my Responses come back without the META variable HTTP_AUTHORIZATION. I also noticed that if I pass "Authorization2" as a header parameter that it is visible in the request:

```
{
    '_content_type': '', 
    'accepted_media_type': 'application/json', 
    '_request': <WSGIRequest
        path:/api/test_auth/,
        GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
        POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
        COOKIES:{
            'MOD_AUTH_CAS_S': 'ba90237b5b6a15017f8ca1d5ef0b95c1',
            'csrftoken': 'VswgfoOGHQmbWpCXksGUycj94XlwBwMh',
            'sessionid': 'de1f3a8eee48730dd34f6b4d41caa210'
        },
        META:{
           'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/etc/apache2/htdocs',
           'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
           'HTTPS': '1',
           'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
           'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
           'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
           'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
           'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION2': 'Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4c',
           ...
```

My first guess is that the authorization header is being removed by apache, and I have read a few S/O questions that state that apache will throw out the value if it does not match basic authorization and authenticate, but I have no idea how to allow the Authorization header to 'pass through' to Django and the WSGIRequest. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I also use mod_auth_cas and mod_proxy, if that changes anything..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question minutes after asking it. But it turns out it was apache2 after all! After crawling the webs and looking through a few search results I found this in a comment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Adding the above lines to my conf file seemed to solve all of my problems! Hopefully this helps users down the road!

Comment: There is an open ticket to document this apache behavior: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/488  If anyone can shed some light on eg. Nginx behaviour in this regard that'd also be helpful.

Comment: @Tom Christie, this is how you do it with nginx: proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization; proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization; proxy_set_header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene I saw a few notes around that when I was digging.  Presumably that only applies when using Nginx as a proxy. (?)

Comment: This worked for me. Note that I had to put the rewrite rule inside the <VirtualHost> statement I needed it enabled for.

Comment: This works, but apparently, when no Authorization header is sent, this will create an empty one. Is there a way to not get an Authorization header when none is sent?

Comment: But if I'm not using Apache?

Comment: In iIS , how to do that ?

Answer (score 86):

If you are using Apache and mod_wsgi, then I found the easy solution to this in the official Django REST framework website

> **Apache mod_wsgi specific configuration**
>
> Note that if deploying to Apache using mod_wsgi, the authorization header is not passed through to a WSGI application by default, as it is assumed that authentication will be handled by Apache, rather than at an application level.
>
> If you are deploying to Apache, and using any non-session based authentication, you will need to explicitly configure mod_wsgi to pass the required headers through to the application. This can be done by specifying the WSGIPassAuthorization directive in the appropriate context and setting it to 'On'.

```
# this can go in either server config, virtual host, directory or .htaccess 
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Comment: Thank you for the update.  This applies to Tastypie non-session based authentication as well.

Comment: This is NOT always the solution. If did deploy Django in Apache with fcgid (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#apache-shared-hosting), you must tell mod_fcgid to pass "Authentication" header by adding (usually in vhost.cof):  FcgidPassHeader Authorization

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I added it to my sites-enabled .conf file and restarted apache, but to no avail. i keep getting the redirect for authentication. any ideas?

Comment: Thanks - this solution is also not Django-specific, it worked for me with Apache2 + uwsgi + web.py

Comment: I have a case where a mobile app sending Authorization Header gets striped only on some certain request, I wonder why!

Comment: I was start to blaming bitnami because some bad configuration until I found your answer, thank you very much

Comment: Delete the cookies or use private mode to check if the solution did fix your problems.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you :) Running Django 4.0.3 on apache2 + mod_wsgi configured with ELB to use HTTPS. Authentication header was being stripped from API requests from Thunder client (vscode extension). Added this line to the sites-available .conf file, restarted the server and now it works :)

Answer (score 19):

It depends on which kind of Django/Apache deployment you did. You need to tell the correct Apache module to allow to pass "Authentication" HTTP header:

- Apache/mod_wsgi:

  `WSGIPassAuthorization On`
- Apache/mod_fcgid:

  `FcgidPassHeader Authorization`

In other words: many Apache modules filters "Authentication" HTTP header, so Django will not receive it. You have to be sure your Django App is receiving it in request.

See:
[django_rest doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#apache-mod_wsgi-specific-configuration) and [Apache fcgid doc](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidpassheader).

NOTE:
After modifying Apache configuration you'll need to restart apache daemon or tell to reload your .cgi file (i.e: `touch my_site_fcgifile.fcgi`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the underscore in the HTTP header `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`. Most webservers just ignores the headers with underscores.

Django dev server also exhibits the same, omitting headers with underscores.

This is the reason why `Authorization2` works.

**A Quick work around is to replace `_` underscores in headers with `-` dashes,**

Ex. changing the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` to **`HTTP-AUTHORIZATION`**

Comment: How i Can make that in iIS ?