# Getting Authorization part of request header in python cgi script in Apache

Tags: python, apache, http, cgi

I'm developing a simple python (v 2.7) CGI script (running apache 2.4.9 on Windows 64).

It seems like most of the data passed to the CGI script is done through environment variables and there is pretty much a 1 to 1 correspondence between the header fields and the environment variables (Accept-Language turns into HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, Referer turns into HTTP_REFERER etc.).

I'm sending Authorization header to my script but for some reason not being passed into an environment variable. Do anyone know how to make that happen or how I can get to it in some other way? I can clearly tell from my CGI log and my web browser that the header field is in there, it's just not being made available to the script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorization header missing in django rest\_framework, is apache to blame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387516/authorization-header-missing-in-django-rest-framework-is-apache-to-blame)

Comment: Looks like the same thing, trying it out!