# Apache strips down "Authorization" header

Tags: django, apache, oauth-2.0, mod-wsgi

I'm having a little issue with my Apache 2.2.15 Server.
I'm running a Django app on top of it with mod_wsgi. I activated `WSGIPassAuthorization On`, which made the Basic auth working well. But I recently implemented OAuth2.0 to secure my API (Implicit Grant), and I think Apache won't let it pass since it is of the form "Authorization: Bearer token". The "Bearer" is the issue I guess, though I don't know how to avoid that.

I tried :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

In the httpd.conf, .htaccess (after setting `AllowOverride All`), and in my vhost. Nothing to do, doesn't work.
I've crawled the Internet all day long, and didn't find anything but those two solutions.

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT:**

```
OS : RedHatEL6.4
Apache : 2.2.15
Django: 1.6.6 w/ django-oauth-toolkit
Python: 2.7.8
```

Comment: I believe [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13387616/2634075) is what you are looking for? I know this is the same code as you have used - but how sure are you that apache is reading either **a) Your .htaccess file** *or* **b) The httpd.conf file** also please try **restarting apache completely** . One thing I noticed with some Python programs is the requirement for having mod_proxy enabled which will give you another layer of complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure about the .htaccess, though almost sure it is reading the httpd.conf (modifications in this file influence the server's behaviour). Is there any particular place in the file I should put those lines though ? Thank you for your answer btw, and I just checked, mod_proxy is activated. I restarted with `apachectl restart` and `apachectl stop; apachectl start`, didn't solve the issue :/.

Comment: Ok to start with what you need to run is `service httpd restart` to restart apache properly on a RH/CentOS server. This could be causing you issues. **ALSO** I would not make these changes at all to http.conf as this is the main configuration file for apache - **NOT** the configuration file for your website. You want to edit things in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/yourSite.conf` so I would suggest looking there and undoing any changes you did to the default apache configuration.

Comment: If you want to read a simple tutorial on configuring Apache on a RH server see [HERE](thedevshed.co.uk/posts/basic-security-for-apache-and-php-on-centos)

Comment: My Vhost is in conf.d/mysite.conf ;) !
Just tried the `service httpd restart`, didn't solve the issue, but it's good to know for the future. I will take care modifying only mysite.conf from now on, and thank you for the help and the link to the tutorial !

Comment: Then *why* are you editing things in `httpd.conf` !? This is apache configuration! Make changes to your site config and leave apache as default as possible apart from any security edits you may choose

Comment: Because I was getting desperate, and tried everything I could, just in case haha. Won't do it anymore Sir, I promise.

Comment: haha please read the tutorial link I showed you - it will give a good insight into what you should do with your config files and what **not** to do with them :P add these edits into your site config file and restart apache with `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I solved my problem, which finally was totally unrelated to my Apache configuration. So if you found this topic looking for an answer to the same problem, one of the solutions below should fix it :

Config WSGI :

```
WSGIPAssAuthorization On
```

Config .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

You can put both of those into your httpd/conf.d/project.conf file !

Comment: needed to add this also `SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0` to `.htaccess`

Comment: @Simo This helped me a lot.

Comment: @simo @Volt - the `RewriteRule` and the `SetEnvIf` directives actually do the same thing (set the environment variable `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` to the contents of the `Authorization` header), so only one of the two should be necessary.

Comment: I've tried "WSGIPAssAuthorization On" and "RewriteEngine" lines above. "Authorization" header started to appear, but was empty. So I've dropped all these lines and added just one line recommended by @simo - it started to work as expected! Thanks.

Comment: Added just the "WSGIPAssAuthorization On" to apache config and it's working now.  Thanks!

Comment: I came across this and have tried all three items.  `WSGIPassAuthorization On` doesn't work as we don't have the module/version required.  The `Rewrite Engine` and `SetEnvIf` lines did the same thing - but in our case Android shows correctly but IOS shows an empty Authorization value.

Comment: Thanks !! Works like a charm. Was stuck on this for a day.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-configure-apache-server-with-django-for-deployment-on-virtual-machine if someone needs more detailed view of this

Comment: I would recommend using `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)` instead of `... ^(.*)` to avoid matching if the header is not present.

Answer (score 12):

Several modules will strip the Authorization header to try to enhance security by preventing scripts from seeing usernames, passwords, etc... unless the developer explicitly enables this.  Many of these modules will allow this header if you simply add the following line to .htaccess: `CGIPassAuth on` (source: [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#cgipassauth) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers))

Comment: thanks, spent a whole day debugging this issue!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I just add `WSGIPassAuthorization On` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mySite.conf` file, as follows:

```
        ...
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/X/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess sepanta_dev python-path=/home/X python-home=/home/X/venv
        ...
```