# Symfony missies “Authorization” header when PHP run as module

Tags: php, apache, symfony, mod-rewrite

This has been asked before, but. I'm trying to implement JWT token auth with PHP 7 on apache 2.4. The script (symfony) never sees the `Authorization` header.

I've read [Apache strips down "Authorization" header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549250/apache-strips-down-authorization-header) and already added:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

to no avail. `mod_rewrite` is enabled and php loaded as module.

My simple test case is

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0....." http://localhost/test.php
```

I'm totally lost as to what else could potentially be needed to get the `Authorization` header into php?

**Update**

Thanks to Olaf Dietsche I've found that the header is present via `apache_request_headers()`. So the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` is not part of `$_SERVER` but can be accessed using the Apache functions.
I've opened https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19693 and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72915 for further investigation.

Comment: Why do you think Apache removes this header? How do you retrieve it?

Comment: I'm dumping `$request->headers` and have move additional code into `ServerBag`. Everything is there- but not the `Authorization` header. As soon as I use another header name it's there, too.

Comment: Have you also looked into [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)? Maybe Symfony ignores the header.