# Unable to get Authorization Header in Flask JWT Extended

Tags: python, flask, http-headers, flask-jwt-extended

I am trying to using to use Flask-JWT extended at the basic level at the moment.
I get the user and password authenticated from the user form. I create an accesss token, include it in the response and route to another protected route. Please find the shorter version of code as below...

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_jwt_extended import,JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token,get_jwt_identity)
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'
jwt = JWTManager(app)
app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['headers']
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED'] = True
jwt = JWTManager(app)
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True


@log_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
form = LoginForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
        if error is None and username = form.request['user'] and pwd = form.request['pwd'] :
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
            resp = redirect(url_for('log_blueprint.protected'),access_token)
            resp.headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}
            return resp

@log_blueprint.route('/protected', methods=["POST","GET"])
@jwt_required
def protected():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_user), 200
```

It gives me the error as below...

```
 {"msg":"Missing Authorization Header"}
```

I tried the answers on this page...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087743/flask-restful-noauthorizationerror-missing-authorization-header
But couldnt get better.
Please let me know any solution for this issue.
Sorry if any typo mistake.

Thanks and regards,
Abhinay J K

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version you are using, accordind to [change log](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v4_upgrade_guide/#encoded-jwt-changes-important) of latest stable version, you should be using notation like:

```
@log_blueprint.route('/protected', methods=["POST","GET"])
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_user), 200
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postman to send request, make sure you check the "key".

Answer (score 0):

If it works on your local machine but not on the server, make sure that your server accepts Authorization headers. See the answer here: [Apache strips down "Authorization" header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549250/apache-strips-down-authorization-header)