# authenticate in wordpress Api using Basic Auth plugin not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api

I am using wp-api-v2 and [Basic Auth plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) to add post to my wordpress. it work nice in my local wamp server but wen i upload my code on online server my credential not working and prevent me to aading new post by this error:

> "Sorry, you are not allowed to create new posts."

I add my credential by putting this key/value pair to my request header:

```
key=>"Authorization",
value=>"Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password)
```

is there any Possibility for misconfiguration or problem in my server?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387516/authorization-header-missing-in-django-rest-framework-is-apache-to-blame) and resolve my problem.