# request.headers.get('Authorization') is empty in Flask production

Tags: python, http, flask, authorization

I have the following flask method that simple returns back the value of the Authorization header:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
   return jsonify({"data" : request.headers.get('Authorization') })
```

When I submit the following curl request to my API which has been deployed to a DO instance, the header comes back as null:

curl --data '' -H "Authorization: test" api.mysite.com/test

```
{
 "data": null
}
```

Yet when I submit the same request on my instance running locally it returns the header contents

```
{
  "data": "test"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Apache needed some additional configuration denoted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387516/authorization-header-missing-in-django-rest-framework-is-apache-to-blame

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a proper `Authorization` header? Possibly the header is being filtered out by a web application firewall or proxy because it doesn't specify a scheme. For example:

```
curl --data '' -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" api.mysite.com/test
```

This sends a basic authorization header with the base64 encoded credentials `username:password`.

Comment: I gave that a shot but it still doesn't seem to work. I think it may need some additional apache configuration to work. I'll have to see...

Comment: Just found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387516/authorization-header-missing-in-django-rest-framework-is-apache-to-blame

Answer (score 0):

On Google Cloud Functions (python 3.10 + Flask), I've been able to get the *Authorization* header as follows:

```py
request.environ.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
```