# Why authorization header not included in request ? - Auth0

Tags: python, authentication, flask, authorization, auth0

I have been struggling with this problem for two weeks, Basically I have configured the auth0 settings with my Flask app which runs on local host.

So, I have the following two endpoints in my flask app:

- A **public endpoint** which requires no authentication process:

```
@APP.route("/api/public")
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
def public():
    # No access token required to access this route
    
    response = "Hello from a public endpoint! You don't need to be authenticated to see this."
    return jsonify(message=response)
```

- A **private endpoint** which requires authentication:

```
@APP.route("/api/private")
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@cross_origin(headers=["Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"])
@requires_auth
def private():
    # A valid access token is required to access this route
    
    response = "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this."
    return jsonify(message=response)
```

So here is the following scenario:

- I try to log in with the auth0 url that redirects me to universal login page for my app. After successful login, it redirects me to the private end point and I get 401 Un-authorized error.

Whenever I make this request with valid token from the browser it throws 401 error.
With the same token, I call this endpoint using postman it works !!

The reason for that is this request from the browser is not including the Authorization header, unlike postman.

I really don't understand why the browser is not including the Authorization header.

Can someone explains ?

**NOTE:** At first it was working using browser without any problems but suddenly it appeared somehow.

Since the private endpoint requires authentication, whenever I try to access the private end point this function is called:

```
def get_token_auth_header():
    """Obtains the access token from the Authorization Header
    """
    auth = request.headers.get("Authorization", None) # HERE IS THE PROBLEM OCCURRS
    print("REQUEST HEADERS: \n", request.headers)
    if not auth:
        raise AuthError({"code": "authorization_header_missing",
                        "description":
                            "Authorization header is expected"}, 401)

    parts = auth.split()

    if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
        raise AuthError({"code": "invalid_header",
                        "description":
                            "Authorization header must start with"
                            " Bearer"}, 401)
    elif len(parts) == 1:
        raise AuthError({"code": "invalid_header",
                        "description": "Token not found"}, 401)
    elif len(parts) > 2:
        raise AuthError({"code": "invalid_header",
                        "description":
                            "Authorization header must be"
                            " Bearer token"}, 401)

    token = parts[1]
    return token
```

I have been struggling with this for almost two weeks, I tried everything.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Was it printing the Authorization in the headers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387516/authorization-header-missing-in-django-rest-framework-is-apache-to-blame) maybe it is happening with flask too.

Comment: @charchit Unfortunately It did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm copying here the same answer I provided in the [community forum](https://community.auth0.com/t/why-authorization-header-not-included-in-request-auth0/64435/2?u=jesstemporal) in case you still need it ;)

It seems you are missing the authlib configuration ;)

You can [see here how to configure that and use it on your app](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/python?_ga=2.193112878.2041029832.1624475145-1533000164.1617129948&_gl=1*i6thv5*rollup_ga*MTk0NTI2ODMxNS4xNjIxOTY4MTcw*rollup_ga_F1G3E656YZ*MTYyNDUzNjEyMS40OS4xLjE2MjQ1Mzg1NzEuNjA.#initialize-authlib)