# Zend Server Windows - Authorization header is not passed to PHP script

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, apache2

I have a PHP application which needs to perform HTTP Basic authentication independently of the containing Apache server.

On linux machines, with php installed via `apt-get php`, I find that the `Authorization` header does not appear in `$_SERVER`, but is available via `apache_request_headers()` or `getallheaders()`.

On a Windows development machine, with Zend Server 6.1.0 / PHP 5.4, I am unable to get the `Authorization` header value from inside PHP by any of the above methods. How can I get its value?

### mod_fcgid?

I haven't been able to determine it for sure, but it seems like Zend Server may use FCGI to dispatch Apache requests to PHP (for example, the variable `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS` appears in `$_SERVER`).

If that were true, it would explain my problem, as `mod_fcgid` deliberately witholds the `Authorization` header from apps, see http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidpassheader

I tried adding

```
FcgidPassHeader Authorization
```

to my apache `httpd.conf`, but it just complained that:

```
Invalid command 'FcgidPassHeader', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

### mod_fastcgi?

Similarly, perhaps Zend is using `mod_fastcgi`?
Based on this page http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiConfig I tried adding the following to my apache `httpd.conf`:

```
FastCgiConfig -pass-header Authorization
```

again, it just complained that:

```
Invalid command 'FastCgiConfig', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found that I can work around this by adding the following to the apache config on Windows:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

This adds a `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` key to the `$_SERVER` global, just as if the `Authorization` header had been passed through by Apache.

Comment: Does anyone have an explanation why this workaround is needed?

Comment: I think that most of the PHP SAPIs withhold the `Authorization` header by default, "for security".