# Prestashop 1.7 Webservice Authetication Error

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In Prestashop 1.7 I'm trying to interact with webservice using [prestapyt](https://github.com/guewen/prestapyt).

```
from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebServiceDict 
prestashop = PrestaShopWebServiceDict('http:\\hostname.ext\api', 'APIKEY')
ps = prestashop.search('addresses')
```

I get this error

```
prestapyt.prestapyt.PrestaShopAuthenticationError: 'Unauthorized'
```

To try to understand if is an error of the library, I've tryied to connect at the API via browser.

Connecting at http:\hostname.ext\api I get a login request.

Inserting in the username filed the APIKEY and leaving the password field blank [as indicated here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Webservice+one-page+documentation#Webserviceone-pagedocumentation-Accessingthewebservicefromthebrowser) I get the Unauthorized error again.

The authetication works only setting the APIKEY as querystring

```
http:\\hostname.ext\api?&ws_key=APIKEY
```

But this method is not available in prestapyt that user session authetication.

There's some setting on Prestashop that I missed or a way to understand this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem and solved the case in this way.

The problem is not releted to Prestashop or prestapyt but relative to the server configuration (Apache + PHP).

Considering that in my case I'm working in a managed cloud service, I don't have in depth information about that.

But the result of this configuration is that the Authorization header does not appear in the `$_SERVER` variable. The same behavior reported here:

[Why are $_SERVER[“PHP_AUTH_USER”] and $_SERVER[“PHP_AUTH_PW”] not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488656/zend-server-windows-authorization-header-is-not-passed-to-php-script)

I solved adding this statement to the .htaccess file in my Prestashop installation:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489025/1891624).

I hope to help others Prestashop users that incur in the same problem.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have added this line then working fine, but when I enable prestashop SEO friendly url this line getting deleted. And also whether ever prestashop regenerate htaccess file this line is not in htaccess, so same problem is there.