# problems using mod_headers with php-fpm/mod_fastcgi

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fastcgi, php

I'm trying to add [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) headers to every response, across my app.

My first thought was to use mod_headers — I placed this directive in an .htaccess file at the documentroot:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7776000"
```

This works fine on my local setup using Apache 2.2 and mod_php. All resources respond with the appropriate HSTS header.

My deployment environment uses Apache 2.2 and mod_fastcgi and the above technique works for any resource *except* php files.

Another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers) had a similar problem, where incoming *requests* (?) had headers stripped — but I'm concerned about modifying headers of **response** leaving the server.

How can I add response headers to php resources in the context of an .htaccess file?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? The answer from Stephens comment did not work for me :(

Comment: I did not. When I had this problem I moved the responsibility of adding the HSTS header into my application code. I was using Symfony, so it was pretty trivial, although it would still be my preference to configure this at the web-server level :-/

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Did it the same way :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs for mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) you probably need to set the optional `conditional` flag for the header directive.

So in this case, it would become

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7776000"
```

Comment: I don't see the 'optional' flag in your example.

Comment: `always` is the condition.