# Manipulate Headers of PHP response in .htaccess-file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

Is it possible to add headers (defined in a `.htaccess` file) to a response generated by PHP?

I have the following `.htaccess` file in my that should add a Header `TestHeader` to each response delivered by my Apache Webserver:

```
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#  Header unset X-Powered-By
  Header add TestHeader "It works."
#</IfModule>
```

I also have three additional files in that folder:

1. `html.html`

   ```
   <html>content</html>
   ```
2. `1.php`

   ```
   <?php
   echo "<html>content php</html>";
   ```
3. `2.php`

   ```
   <?php
   header("TestHeader: Sent from PHP.");
   echo "<html>content php</html>";
   ```

   - Requesting `html.html` returns the header `TestHeader: "It works."`
   - Requesting `1.php` does **not** return header `TestHeader`
   - Requesting `2.php` returns the header `TestHeader: "Sent from PHP."`

Is it somehow possible to manipulate the response header from PHP output using `.htaccess` directives?

EDIT: PHP runs as `FastCGI` on the server.

Comment: I know this is out of scope but would a PHP only solution solve your problem? A way to set the header once in PHP, but that applies to all PHP scripts

Comment: It *should* work. If, for example, if in `1.php` you do `print_r(apache_response_headers())` you should get an array with `[TestHeader] => It works.` in it (you may need to call `flush()` first).

Comment: @CD001: So you are saying, that PHP somehow removes the headers?

Comment: @BeetleJuice: Actually, I don't want to touch more than one file. `2.php` was only a test.

Comment: Are you using mod_php?

Comment: My point was, that from what you've got here, it *should* work; `1.php` should have `TestHeader: it works.` set... I ran a quick test on my dev box and it was absolutely fine, so I'm not really sure why you're not getting that TestHeader with the PHP file - everything else being equal (like the PHP file is in a directory affected by the .htaccess file and so on).

Comment: @Progrock: PHP runs as `FastCGI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be a problem with your Apache version and the fact that PHP runs as FastCGI.

In Apache 2.2.X there was a bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49308

I found a couple of other posts that propose to use the `always` condition to fix the problem:

```
Header always add TestHeader "It works."
```

Also see:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/152373/mod-headers-not-working-for-php-mod-fastcgi-pages
- https://serverfault.com/questions/383011/mod-headers-not-sending-headers-when-file-is-php
- [problems using mod_headers with php-fpm/mod_fastcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160228/problems-using-mod-headers-with-php-fpm-mod-fastcgi)
- Comments in: [Apache won't set headers for PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147413/apache-wont-set-headers-for-php-script)

Comment: Once you know that you have to search for FastCGI and Headers, you can find quite a few issues :-D ; The version on my server is in fact `2.2.x`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SetEnvIf and then add the header accordingly:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.php$" phpfile
Header set TestHeader "Sent from PHP" env=phpfile
```

If the request URL ends with the extension ".php", then SetEnvIf will set a variable "phpfile". If the variable "phpfile" exists only then  `TestHeader: Sent from PHP` will be sent as a response header.
You can use this logic for as many extensions or URL patterns as you need.

Edit: If the header already exists i.e. it is sent from PHP, then using `Header Set` apache will replace it by the new value.

Comment: The response header sent by PHP can be replaced by using "set" in the .htaccess file