# get authorization header in cakephp at https

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, authorization

I am using Cakephp 2.3
I want to get the authorization header. 
I tried using this code:

```
$this->request->header('Authorization')
```

It does not show anything while using

```
$this->request->header('User-Agent')
```

HTTP_USER_AGENT shows the data. 
Tried using the `apache_request_headers()` function, here also all the headers are displayed except the Authorization header.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Possibly **[https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#Cake\Network\Request::header](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#Cake\Network\Request::header)**. The same would apply to CakePHP 2.x

Comment: Thank you very much. I just fixed it by using this. SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1 in my htaccess file.

Comment: You may want to post that an as an actual answer thenand accept it later on, this will help future readers that are searching for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the question.
If this can help anyone, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers) is the reference that helped me in solving my problem. The actual logic was the Apache Server, It was hiding the Authorization header for security reasons.