# Curl connection refused between applications on Docker container

Tags: php, apache, curl, docker, laradock

I have a website (ZF1) and an API (Laravel) running on the same Docker (Laradock) container. I can access each separately through a browser, but when I make a cURL request from the website to the application, I get a null response and the header returns 0. If I output the cURL errors, then I get this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '[API_ENDPOINT]');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_close ($ch);

echo curl_strerror(curl_errno($ch));

(7) Failed to connect to [API_HOST] port 80: Connection refused
```

However, if I make a cURL request to https://www.google.com from the application, then it returns a result. I also tried using file_get_contents(), but I received no response and the following warning:

```
[Thu May 18 21:41:33.828737 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 949:tid 139999802541824] [client 172.20.0.1:49652] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents
([API_ENDPOINT]): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/projects/[APPLICATION_PATH]/[CONTROLLER].php on line 2367\n', referer: [WEBSITE_HOST]/[URI]
```

I also SSHed into the Apache2 container and was able to make a successful cURL call to the API_ENDPOINT and get the expected data back. I then tried using wget to get the header info and received the following:

```
root@cd3a4177dcfa:/var/log/apache2# wget --header="Host: http://subdomain.example.dev/api/calendarevents" -Os http://localhost
--2017-05-19 07:28:15--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2017-05-19 07:28:16--  (try: 2)  http://localhost/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

In case it is an Apache2 issue, here is my API VirtualHost:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/projects/[API_PROJECT]/public/
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/[API_HOST]-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/[API_HOST]-error.log
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

  <Directory "/var/www/projects/[API_PROJECT]/public/">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all Granted
  </Directory>

  # set environment
  #SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1 // Did not notice a difference in behavior when enabled
  #CGIPassAuth on // Sites stopped loading when enabled
</VirtualHost>
```

And Website VirtualHost:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName [WEBSITE_HOST]
  DocumentRoot /var/www/projects/[WEBSITE_PROJECT]
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/[WEBSITE_HOST]-error.log
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

  <Directory "/var/www/projects/[WEBSITE_PROJECT]/repo">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all Granted
  </Directory>

  # set environment
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
  SetEnv APPLICATION_LOGGING false
  #SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1 // Did not notice a difference in behavior when enabled
  #CGIPassAuth on // Sites stopped loading when enabled
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the Docker info (Windows 10/Hyper V/Docker Version 17.03.1-ce-win12 (12058) Channel: stable)

```
Containers: 9
 Running: 5
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
Images: 233
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.27-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.837 GiB
Name: moby
ID: PE42:IS45:4OO6:JMEQ:NWNB:NQDF:RPEL:JPHJ:L6OP:A5SL:IDP3:F7SV
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 86
 Goroutines: 74
 System Time: 2017-05-19T04:52:50.5943959Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

And these are the containers that I am currently running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
cd3a4177dcfa        laradock_apache2     "/opt/docker/bin/e..."   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   laradock_apache2_1
8ef66cb80a2e        laradock_php-fpm     "docker-php-entryp..."   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          9000/tcp                                   laradock_php-fpm_1
988eff458036        laradock_workspace   "/sbin/my_init"          8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp                       laradock_workspace_1
8be5253e8622        laradock_redis       "docker-entrypoint..."   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                     laradock_redis_1
aa6d8d6ae950        laradock_mysql       "docker-entrypoint..."   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                     laradock_mysql_1
```

I am not sure what is causing the connection to be refused between the two sites on the same container. I checked my php.ini and both curl and allow_url_fopen = on were enabled. I am able access the API_ENDPOINT directly through both browser and CLI cURL and get the expected results. My best guesses at this point are some sort of port conflict, an authorization header being blocked, Apache2 configuration, or some sort of odd Docker/Laradock issue. I also thought it might of been a conflict between Apache2 and PHP-FPM, but the solutions [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers) didn't seem to work for me.

Thank you in advanced for any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: What is the real value of [API_HOST]?

Comment: I am using something other than www for the subdomain:

[API_HOST] => http://subdomain.example.dev
[API_ENDPOINT] => http://subdomain.example.dev/api/endpoint

In my windows host file, I have the website and API set up like this:

127.0.0.1    www.example.dev # Website
127.0.0.1    example.spear.dev # API

Comment: Oh.. that can be the problem. For some reason the `.dev` subdomains **always** resolve as an IP. Try `ping whatever.you.invent.dev`: *PING whatever.you.invent.dev (127.0.53.53): 56 data bytes* So there (127....) maybe there isn't any open port

Comment: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/03/13/google_developer_gtld_domain_icann/

Comment: can you change all `.dev` stuff to something else? Just for testing purposes

Comment: Ok, I changed all of my .dev stuff to .app. No change in behavior. I was able to ping subdomain.example.app from Windows, but I don't seem to have ping on my Laradock containers. So I tried wget instead and received:


wget --header="Host: http://subdomain.example.app/api/endpoint" -Os http://localhost
--2017-05-19 15:59:16--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

Comment: I thought maybe the connection was being refused due to security info not being carried over to requests to port 80, so I tried setting session.secure=false by adding Header edit* Set-Cookie "(JSESSIONID=.*)(; Secure)" "$1" to the relevant VirtualHost files, but I am still getting local connections on port 80 refused.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of adding to extra_hosts of the php-fpm container.
Modify the Apache2 container's Backend network definition and add an alias.
this was you dont have to keep changing the extra_hosts everytime the ip changes

```
    networks:
        frontend:              
        backend:
         aliases:
          - subdomain.example.app
```

Comment: This worked for me when I installed newest version of docker. For old versions of docker try @Xythantiops answer.

Comment: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1776#issuecomment-524735826

Answer (score 3):

I figured out [what was causing my issue](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/435). I needed to add an extra-host to the PHP-FPM section of my docker-compose.yml file. So add:

```
- "subdomain.example.app:10.0.75.1"
```

To extra-hosts. Then you need to rebuild your containers:

```
docker-compose up -d --build apache2 mysql redis
```

And this is what the PHP-FPM section of your docker-compose.yml for Laradock should look like:

```
php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
          - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
          - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION}
          - INSTALL_MYSQLI=true
          - INSTALL_TOKENIZER=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TOKENIZER}
          - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
        dockerfile: "Dockerfile-${PHP_VERSION}"
      volumes_from:
        - applications
      volumes:
        - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      expose:
        - "9000"
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
        - "subdomain.example.app:10.0.75.1"
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
      networks:
        - backend
```

Comment: This worked me when I was using old version of docker. For latest version of docker check @steve sonius answer. It worked for me.

Comment: For new users - https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1776#issuecomment-524735826