# Header Authorization not working on Sub Domain

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have this function for Basic Authorization for my API.

```
private function authorize() {
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    if(isset($headers['Authorization'])){
        if ($headers['Authorization'] == '14abd57ece42d9489aeae6e1865064751') { //'akif&&nadeem'
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works well on my API domain domain.com/api/actionname

But it does not work [Fails Authorization] when I try to access my API via a Sub Domain subdomain.domain.com/api/actionname

All code is correctly in place and API is performing perfectly without Authorization. Any idea how can I fix this?

Output of the Headers is as follows:

```
array(9) {
   ["Host"]=>
     string(24) "ultimate.bleupage.online"
     ["Connection"]=>
     string(10) "keep-alive"
     ["User-Agent"]=>
     string(115) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
     ["Cache-Control"]=>
     string(8) "no-cache"
     ["Postman-Token"]=>
     string(36) "6330a309-ffcf-d72e-936a-bf10ff154d45"
     ["Accept"]=>
     string(3) "*/*"
     ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
     string(13) "gzip, deflate"
     ["Accept-Language"]=>
    string(26) "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
     ["Cookie"]=>
     string(36) "PHPSESSID=p2m0cc7sq7kn8fk2motvrobnn4"
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using some other parameter key than `Authorization`, like `Auth`, because sometimes Apache filters away the Authorization header you can get more info here [Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM and Authorization headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers).

which you can access, like this(with `$_SERVER`):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH']
```

Or Like this(with `apache_request_headers`):

```
apache_request_headers()['Auth'];
```