# Authorization header is empty on PHP var_dump()

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, header, authorization

I'm sending a header to server with the following request headers:

```
Host: xx.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: xx.com
Authorization: Bearer mytoken1234
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Connection: keep-alive
```

On my php file I'm trying to view the headers with var_dump() and it shows following:

```
["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
 ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
  string(23) "en-US,en;q=0.8,fi;q=0.6"
  ["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=>
  string(9) "max-age=0"
  ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
  string(71) "cpsession=scocta5%3aBcbKZGvPoUCv2Yhb%2c2dc8a5c3bd6713b6ab029f16a46980e7"
```

I tried adding following lines to my .htaccess:

```
   SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

or

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
   RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Without these settings, Authorization header was not showing on var_dump() at all but now it's just string(0) "". Why isn't my server getting the Authorization header content?

Comment: If you write var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']); var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']); in a php file what's the output?

Comment: @OfirBaruch both are null.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this code into your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Then you will be able to get the Authorization code by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`

---

*Please, see the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46323802/9492722 to have more information.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [apache_request_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) function:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
var_dump($headers['Authorization']);
```